# Using Groovy collect closure to process list into grouped sublists

Tags: groovy

Given my `Widget` class:

```
class Widget {
    String name
    WidgetType type
    boolean isRad
}

enum WidgetType {
    Fizz, Buzz, Foo
}
```

My groovy code will be handed a `List<Widget>` that *may* be populated like so:

```
List<Widget> allWidgets = []
Widget w1 = new Widget(name: "W1", type: WidgetType.Fizz, isRad: true)
Widget w2 = new Widget(name: "W2", type: WidgetType.Fizz, isRad: true)
Widget w3 = new Widget(name: "W3", type: WidgetType.Buzz, isRad: false)
Widget w4 = new Widget(name: "W4", type: WidgetType.Buzz, isRad: false)
Widget w5 = new Widget(name: "W5", type: WidgetType.Foo, isRad: true)
Widget w6 = new Widget(name: "W6", type: WidgetType.Foo, isRad: false)

allWidgets << w1
allWidgets << w2
allWidgets << w3
allWidgets << w4
allWidgets << w5
allWidgets << w6
```

What I want to accomplish is the grouping of all elements in `allWidgets` according to their `Widget#type`. So effectively, turning the above list into multiple lists (1 per `type`) like so:

```
List<Widget> fizzWidgets = []
List<Widget> buzzWidgets = []
List<Widget> gooWidgets = []
Widget w1 = new Widget(name: "W1", type: WidgetType.Fizz, isRad: true)
Widget w2 = new Widget(name: "W2", type: WidgetType.Fizz, isRad: true)
Widget w3 = new Widget(name: "W3", type: WidgetType.Buzz, isRad: false)
Widget w4 = new Widget(name: "W4", type: WidgetType.Buzz, isRad: false)
Widget w5 = new Widget(name: "W5", type: WidgetType.Foo, isRad: true)
Widget w6 = new Widget(name: "W6", type: WidgetType.Foo, isRad: false)

fizzWidgets << w1
fizzWidgets << w2

buzzWidgets << w3
buzzWidgets << w4

fooWidgets << w5
fooWidgets << w6
```

I *believe* that the `collect` closure can be used here, but all my attempts thus far have failed, my best being:

```
allWidgets.collect { widget ->
    it.type
}
```

Any ideas what I can do here? And while I would *accept* a pure Java answer, I'm really hoping for something really elegant and...well, groovy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is not `collect` but `groupBy`:

```
allWidgets.groupBy { it.type }
```

As a result a `Map<WidgetType, List<Widget>>` will be returned.

Demo:

```
enum WidgetType {
    Fizz, Buzz, Foo
}

class Widget {
    String name
    WidgetType type
    boolean isRad
}

List<Widget> allWidgets = [
    Widget w1 = new Widget(name: "W1", type: WidgetType.Fizz, isRad: true),
    Widget w2 = new Widget(name: "W2", type: WidgetType.Fizz, isRad: true),
    Widget w3 = new Widget(name: "W3", type: WidgetType.Buzz, isRad: false),
    Widget w4 = new Widget(name: "W4", type: WidgetType.Buzz, isRad: false),
    Widget w5 = new Widget(name: "W5", type: WidgetType.Foo, isRad: true),
    Widget w6 = new Widget(name: "W6", type: WidgetType.Foo, isRad: false),
]

def grouped = allWidgets.groupBy { it.type }
List<Widget> fizzWidgets = grouped[WidgetType.Fizz]
List<Widget> buzzWidgets = grouped[WidgetType.Buzz]
List<Widget> fooWidgets = grouped[WidgetType.Foo]

assert fizzWidgets.size() == 2
assert fizzWidgets.every { it.type == WidgetType.Fizz }
assert buzzWidgets.size() == 2
assert buzzWidgets.every{ it.type == WidgetType.Buzz }
assert fooWidgets.size() == 2
assert fooWidgets.every { it.type == WidgetType.Foo }


assert grouped instanceof Map
assert grouped.keySet().every { it instanceof WidgetType }
assert grouped.values().every { it instanceof List }
assert grouped.values().flatten().every { it instanceof Widget }
```

[Here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#groupBy(Iterable%3CT%3E,%20Closure%3CK%3E)) you can find `groupBy` docs.

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) - I'm trying to find documentation on `groupBy` but no real luck. In your example above, is `def grouped` really a `Map<WidgetType, List<Widget>>`? Or something else?

Comment: See my edit. Since generics are erased at runtime have a look at additional assert statements. They prove `grouped` type as well as keys and values types.